# Side length of a square in a squared rectangle

Tags: geometry

I have a *squared rectangle* where I want to find the side length of a sub-square (for the record, [consult the omniscient Google](http://goo.gl/ww1q7k)).

[image: diagram]

**Here's what I've already done.**

$$14 + 4 + x = \mathrm{height}.$$
The teeny square has a side length of 1.
If the square to the right of the tiny square has side length $a$, $$x = 9 + a - 1.$$ This problem would be a lot easier if the rectangle were a square (if you think it is, prove it), but I'm not sure what to do now.

Comment: Just detective work, real quick. It is $7+8$

Comment: @AndréNicolas Could you explain (or hint at) that in an answer?

Comment: Done, I hope what I wrote is clear. Unfortunately, I cannot point online, and the squares are not labelled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We do some side-chasing.

The square below the $14$ is $10\times 10$.

So the square to the right of that is $7\times 7$. (Here the fact that the teeny square is $1\times 1$ is used.)

The square to the right of the $9$ is $8\times 8$.

So the mystery square has side $7+8$.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

left middle square is 10, because 14-4
tiny square is 1, because 10-9
square below tiny is 8, because 9-1
square to the right of tiny is 7, because 8-1

x is 15, 7+8

The answer is
E) 15